# MariaDB Understanding "Event" Interval

Tags: mariadb, log, event

I've created my first EVENT:

```sql
ALTER EVENT flush_logs_event 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 6 HOUR 
COMMENT 'Rotate /var/log/mysql/master-bin*' 
DO FLUSH LOGS;
```

I changed it from "12" to "6" because of how fast the log is growing for replication.  I want it rotating by time and not file size to make deploying additional slaves easier for me.

I thought "6 Hour" means 6H00 12H00 18H00 and 24H00.  At the same time I altered the event I also made a tweak to /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
expire_logs_days=7
```

And then I did

```
systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

The master-bin rotated when MariaDB re-stared.  It created **master-bin.000006**.  When I restarted MariaDB it was ~5:21.  Does this mean the master-bin will rotate at 11:21, 17:21, etc.?

For full disclosure I am also including:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show events \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: mysql
                Name: flush_logs_event
             Definer: root@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                Type: RECURRING
          Execute at: NULL
      Interval value: 6
      Interval field: HOUR
              Starts: 2021-12-09 05:21:23
                Ends: NULL
              Status: ENABLED
          Originator: 1
character_set_client: utf8mb4
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought "6 Hour" means 6H00 12H00 18H00 and 24H00.

No. This means "6 hours from previous start". You have no specidfied any timepoint as a base - and server uses previous event starting time for this purposes.

If you want the event to be fired at listed hours you must specify STARTS schedule option - in this case the specified value will be used as a base. Like

```sql
ALTER EVENT flush_logs_event 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 6 HOUR 
            STARTS '2021-12-09 00:00:00'
COMMENT 'Rotate /var/log/mysql/master-bin*' 
DO FLUSH LOGS;
```

Comment: For future reference: It is also worth nothing I've had to edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf .  I needed to add " event_scheduler = ON " to [mariadb] .  It is also noteworthy that the command " SHOW PROCESSLIST; " will confirm last time events have run.